# undefined reference (templates)

Tags: c++, class, templates, namespaces

I have a namespace that gets built out of a .cpp and .h
lots of classes use this namespace and call the template functions from within it 
How do I fix all the undefined references during the linking process?
Where would I put all the definitions of the template functions?
could someone show me an example of a namespace that uses templates and then a class that uses that namespace and can successfully call one of the templated functions without error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're incorrectly placing template definitions in the .cpp file.

For more information about that, see the FAQ item ["Why can't I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12).

The immediately following FAQ items may also be of help to you, but it's not entirely clear what your question is about (in detail).

Cheers & hth.,